# Is there a better way, with the DocuSign API, of checking whether a purge has occurred?

Tags: docusignapi

In a project that uses the DocuSign C# SDK I am setting up an automated archival process. One step involves putting envelopes in the purge queue via API; and another step involves checking that the envelopes that were queued 14 days ago were actually purged.

I have found that I can use the ListAuditEvents API to make this check (by going through the AuditEvents list exposed by the result and seeing if there are any entries like this

```json
{
...
"name":"Action","value":"Documents Purged"
...
}
```

My question is, is there a "better" way to do this? ("Better" as in: is quicker / uses less bandwith.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can suggest is for you to use [DocuSign Monitor API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/monitor-api/) may be another way to do this which may be better for your needs.

See [How to get Monitoring data](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/monitor-api/how-to/get-monitoring-data/), which you can also download as part of the [quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) (change API to "Monitor") and confirm it shows purged events.

But as far as I know there's no specific API endpoint that I know of that will just do what you want.

Comment: It's an interesting feature which I wasn't aware of, but I don't think it fits this particular use case.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: I asked for a method that was simpler and/or faster and/or uses less bandwidth than the one using ListAuditEvents. Using the monitoring API seems less simple; and appears to involve more bandwidth (I haven't tested this however). It seems like overkill to me ("how to tell if a document has been purged? load the logs for all activity on the account and then go through them"...!).

Comment: Yes, so no , there's no specific API endpoint that I know of that will just do what you want.

Comment: Thanks; if you update your answer with this info then I'll "accept" it.